# SED to find and replace exact word beginning with $

Tags: sed, tr

My php file has some defined variables with $downtime_hosts, what i need is a single command to just find and replace entire  `$downtime_hosts = 8;` into `$downtime_hosts = 15;` and without affecting the other `$downtime_hosts` used several time within the file.

here my number 8,15,16 may change anytime, what i need is find the line beginning with`$downtime_hosts = anyinteger` and simply replace with my new line $downtime_hosts = newinteger . please note `anyinteger / newinteger=2,3,4,15`or any

`$downtime_hosts = 8;`

`$total_hosts = $all_hosts - $downtime_hosts;`

`if ($host_up == $total_hosts )`

`Hosts under downtime $downtime_hosts`
`

Any inputs are really welcomed !

Answer (score 4):

```
sed 's/$downtime_hosts = 8;/$downtime_hosts = 15;/' file.php
```

The `$` poses no problem since it won't act as an anchor unless it's found at the end of the pattern.  The `sed` script does need to be single-quoted though a the shell otherwise would try to expand `$downtime_hosts` as a shell variable.

To only match the pattern in the beginning of a line:

```
sed 's/^$downtime_hosts = 8;/$downtime_hosts = 15;/' file.php
```

If the integer 8 could be any integer:

```
sed 's/^$downtime_hosts = [0-9]*;/$downtime_hosts = 15;/' file.php
```

To replace the integer with an integer held by a shell variable `$newint`:

```
sed "s/^\$downtime_hosts = [0-9]*;/\$downtime_hosts = $newint;/" file.php
```

Notice that we now have to use double quotes around the `sed` editing script for the shell to expand the `$newint` variable. This also means that we are forced to escape the two existing `$` from the shell.

Comment: Why doesn't it require `^`  as i was looking for just the line that contains from the beginning, the whole time i was trying using this.. but it just an stupidity i was trying .. can you elaborate a little more about it my dear friend.

Comment: @KunalSaha If you require the match to be anchored to the beginning of the line (this was not specified in the question), then yes, you should add `^` to the beginning of the pattern.

Comment: here my number 8,15,16 may change anytime, what i need is find the line beginning with` $downtime_hosts = anyineger` and simply replace with my new line `$downtime_hosts = newinteger` . please note anyinteger / newinteger=2,3,4,15 or any.

Comment: @KunalSaha Are you going to have lines starting with $downtime_hosts that will not have "= integer" but something else, i.e an expression?

Comment: @KunalSaha You are aware that you are continuing to change the question? This was not what you asked. I will however update my answer, because I'm a nice guy.

Comment: @George Vasiliou - might be no, not at all, as it is used to set a variable.

Comment: @Christopher I prefer `sed` without `-i` to a new file and then `mv` to replace the original. Partly for the portability issues with `-i` on different Unices, and partly because it's safer while testing. It was unclear from the question if the pattern may match multiple lines in the file. He says "the line", so I must assume that there is only one such line.

Comment: @Christopher Sorry, I forgot to say something about the `1` flag at the end of the `s` `sed` command that you mentioned. The `1` is the default if the flags are empty, i.e. only the first match on the input line will be substituted.